# Specflow Resharper test runner navigate to feature file

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, specflow

Is there a consistant way of navigating from a test in a Resharper test session to the feature file?  When I double click a test in the session window most of the time it takes me the `*.feature.cs` and not the '*.feature'.  However sometime this does work.  Is this a bug?  I found these things already:

[How to navigate to feature file from resharper test session window in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447674/how-to-navigate-to-feature-file-from-resharper-test-session-window-in-visual-stu)

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206649425-Navigating-to-SpecFlow-Features-from-Test-Runner

But not much else.  Is there some jedi/ninja trick I'm missing to get this to work the same way everytime, i.e. double click the test in the session window and go to the feature file

Comment: I believe this is a resharper issue, with it not respecting the #line pragmas in the generated code, as this functionality works fine in NCrunch (ie it navigates to the feature file)

Comment: @SamHolder Thanks mate, I think your right.  We did some playing around and if the test fails it goes to the feature file but if the test is green then it goes to the `feature.cs` file . . . brilliant

Comment: do yourself a favour and invest in NCrunch. It will totally change your life. (disclaimer: I love NCrunch). I never use resharpers test runner any more.

Comment: @SamHolder hahaha, been there, done that.  It's too chatty for me, I like to test first the old school way.  I'll leave it to you crazy Brighton kids

Answer (score 0):

What you can do when it takes you to the generated code is to right click in the code, click navigate, then click related files, and you'll see the feature file there. A bit long winded I know but it works.

Comment: That's mate, yes I know I could but it would be nice if resharper worked a little better.